# Is there a priority when purchasing shul supplies?

Tags: synagogue

When buying supplies for a new shul, is there a priority on which items should be purchased first, second, etc.? Assume that there is enough in the budget to buy only some of the items, but not all of them, or the shul is trying to raise funds for these items. Is there an order among these items that they should focus on? (Sources, please):

- siddurim
- chumashim
- Torah
- shulchan (Torah reader's table)
- amud (stand for chazzan at front of shul) - Note - technically, the chazzan can daven at the shulchan, from my understanding. For purposes of this question, I'm just concerned if there is a priority on what to allocate first.

Comment: How can a Shul function without a Torah??

Comment: @DoubleAA I said **purchasing** one. Assume that they have one on loan, for now.

Comment: @DoubleAA Or it's just a Friday night minyan. (For example)

Comment: @scim then why would they ever need one? Simchat Torah on Shabbat?

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant currently just Friday night, but with plans to expand.